# Almost sure convergence + convergence in distribution implies joint convergence in distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, almost-everywhere

I'm wondering, if I have two sequences of random variables $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$, defined on the same probability space, such that $X_n\stackrel{a.s.}{\rightarrow}X$ and $Y_n\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}Y$, is it possible to conclude that they converge jointly in distribution, i.e. $$ (X_n,Y_n)\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}(X,Y) $$ as $n\to\infty$?

I believe that this question is closely related to the following: if $Y_n\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}Y$, is it true that $$ (X,Y_n)\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}(X,Y) $$ as $n\to \infty$?

Thank you in advance for any thoughts, comments etc.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second question, take $Y_n = X$, and $Y$ to be independent of $X$ with the same distribution. This implies that the answer to your first question is also no.

Comment: Thank you Nate! This seems as a good counterexample. It looks like that, in general, such result cannot be true. I'm wondering, how $X_n$ and $Y_n$ must be related, in order that such claim holds? Of course, some sort of "minimal" assumptions would be interesting. Perhaps, if $\phi$ is measurable function, and $Y_n= \phi(X_n)$, for every $n$, would be enough?

Comment: You're going to need to know something about $Y$ as well. In a sense, convergence in distribution isn't really a convergence of random variables, but of probability measures. It can't distinguish between random variables with the same distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Convergence in distribution is the weakest form of convergence. Thus, $X_{n}\rightarrow_{a.s} X$ implies that $X_{n}\rightarrow_{d} X$. One can then prove from this that $(Y_{n},c)\rightarrow_{d}(Y,c)$ for any constant $c$ by using the definition of convergence: $E(f(Y_{n},c))\rightarrow E(f(Y,c))$ for any bounded function $f$.

Then, simply show that $(Y_{n},X_{n})\rightarrow_{d}(Y_{n},X)$ which is obvious using the definition of convergence in probability(which again implies convergence in distribution). Thus, you obtain that $(Y_{n},X_{n})\rightarrow_{d} (Y_{n},X)\rightarrow_{d} (Y,X)$ where here we take $X=c$ from the previous paragraph. Thus you have your result that $(Y_{n},X_{n})\rightarrow_{d}(Y,X)$.

Comment: The first part is a result of Portmanteau's theorem/lemma.

Comment: Thank you  Thomas for your comments. I'm aware of Portmanteau theorem and I'm a little bit confused by your argument of taking $X=c$, because (as far as I understand) c in Portmanteau theorem must be non-random constant? If I put $X=c$, this equality is in what sense? Since, I did not assume that $X$ is degenerate random variable, it cannnot be $X=c$ a.s., for any (non-random) constant $c$. So, I'm not sure, this is right, but may be I'm wrong?

Comment: You are correct! I misread the problem(apologies). You would need convergence in probability, $Y_{n}\rightarrow_{p} Y$, for your statement to hold. Then, using $X_{n}\rightarrow_{a.s}X$ implies $X_{n}\rightarrow_{p} X$, and then applying the definition of $p$ convergence for $(X_{n},Y_{n})$ you would get your result.

Comment: Yes, convergence in probability of both coordinates implies joint convergence in probability. It is interesting, how "weak" the weak convergence is :), that even the a.s. convergence on the other coordinate does not help in general. Thanks anyway!!